# Gesture Recognizers and TableView

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView which covers all of a UITableView.
The UIView is using gesture recognizers for control of what the table displays.
I still need the vertical UITableView scrolling and row taps.
How do I pass these on to the table from the gesture recognizers?

Comment: I believe "[tablView gesture]" should be "[yourTableView addGestureRecognizer:gesture]"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assign your gesture to the table view and the table will take care of it:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[gesture setDirection:
        (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft
        |UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[tableView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[gesture release];
```

Then in your gesture action method, act based on the direction:

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        [self moveLeftColumnButtonPressed:nil];
    }
    else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        [self moveRightColumnButtonPressed:nil];
    }
}
```

The table will only pass you the gestures you have asked for after handling them internally.

Comment: This is the great answer. But can you please tell me how to know the tableview indexPath in handleSwipeFrom method?

Comment: This won't work - the direction property on UISwipeGestureRecognizer indicates what directions CAN be recognised (in this case left AND right) not what direction WAS swiped. You will need to separate gesture recognisers

Comment: Yes, recognizer.direction will always be 3 and never match.  This is arguably a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319209/setting-direction-for-uiswipegesturerecognizer

Answer (score 31):

If you need to know your cell's indexPath:

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint swipeLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
}
```

This was previously answered in [UIGestureRecognizer and UITableViewCell issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604667/213987).

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for this solution. I had no clue `locationInView` thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

I tried Rob Bonner's suggestion and it works great. thank you.

But, in my case, there's a problem with direction recognition. (recognizer.direction always refer 3) I'm using IOS5 SDK and Xcode 4.

It seems caused by "[gesture setDirection:(left | right)]" I think. (because predefined (dir left | dir right) calculation result is 3)

So, if someone has problem like me and want to recognize swipe left and right seprately, then assign two recognizer to table view with different directions.

Like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                             initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[swipeLeftGesture setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                              initWithTarget:self 
                                              action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];

[swipeRightGesture setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

[tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
[tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
```

and gesture action below:

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self moveLeftColumnButtonPressed:nil];
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self moveRightColumnButtonPressed:nil];
}
```

I coded with ARC feature then if you are not using ARC, add release codes.

PS: My english is not so good, so if there's any sentential error, correction will be very pleased :)