# Enter edit mode with single row/cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, editmode

I have a custom swipe recognition class from this example:
[How to detect a swipe-to-delete gesture in a customized UITableviewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167756/how-to-detect-a-swipe-to-delete-gesture-in-a-customized-uitableviewcell)

```
    - (void)cellSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    }
}
```

Now I would like to select that single row at the indexPath and enable edit mode for it, could someone show me how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Cache the row you want somewhere and in your implementation of `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` just only return `YES` for the row you want to be editable.  Then enter edit mode by sending `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but I'm quite new to the iOS programming yet and I don't exactly understand what have to be done. I did something like this and it doesn't seem to work.  if ([notifTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        [[notifTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        return YES;

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable in your class that is an `NSIndexPath *index` then have

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath == self.index;
}
```

And set index to whatever cell you want to be able to edit, then call `tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES/NO` whenever you want to edit that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

In your  tableView `didSelectRowAtIndex` delegate method call the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 [yourTableView.delegate tableView:tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

In `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

  }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



}
```