# Get swiped tableviewcell from tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I need your help..

I've got an `UIPanGesture` in my custom `TableViewCell`.
I should need to determine which cell has been panned in `UITableView`'s `UIViewController`.

I have two problems:

1. How can I get panned `TableViewCell` (maybe through indexpath)..
2. Where should I put the code inside `UITableView`'s methods to get it.

Thank you very much!!!

Andrea

Comment: what is your purpose to do that?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I've already found panned tableview cell inside its class, but I don't know how to pass it inside tableview's uiviewcontroller. Before this edit, I had a swipe gesture initialized directly in cellForRowAtIndexPath's method and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to figure out on what part of a UITableView a UIPanGesture ended, is that right?

I would use the UITableView method indexPathForRowAtPoint: to get you your indexPath.

I have no experience with gesture recognizers, but I'll update my answer if I have the opportunity to get a working example. If you can elaborate on what the UIPanGesture is doing or why you need the UITableViewCell specifically, that would help.

Comment: Exactly! In other words I need to figure out in which cell the gesture has been done!!

Answer (score 0):

If Im reading your question correctly, it sounds like you want to add swipe gestures to each table view cell and then be able to get the index of that cell. If this is what you are looking for, you could always do the following. This appears similar to this question: [How to detect a swipe-to-delete gesture in a customized UITableviewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167756/how-to-detect-a-swipe-to-delete-gesture-in-a-customized-uitableviewcell) But I did include the implementation for you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Do what you need to to get your current cell
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:@"prototypeCellId";

    //create swipe gesture and add it to cell
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwiped:)];
    [swipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

    return cell;
}

- (void)cellSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //do what you want with the indexPath (or cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the gesture is initialized in uitableview's cell (due to pan gesture implementation).

Comment: I solved my problem with this line of code:


`SCViewController *vista = (SCViewController*)tableview.dataSource;

 vista.swipedIndexPath = _PannedIndexpath; `

With this way, i send to table view swiped cell's index path, which is located in uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this line of code: SCViewController *vista = (SCViewController*)tableview.dataSource; vista.swipedIndexPath = _PannedIndexpath; With this way, i send to table view swiped cell's index path, which is located in uitableviewcell.