# UITableViewCell How can I detect that the user has swiped left or Right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) and I want to know the action that is triggered when the user swipe Left or Right.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167756/how-to-detect-a-swipe-to-delete-gesture-in-a-customized-uitableviewcell

Comment: This approach only recognize the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` State

Comment: @ahmedlabib it have multiple options for `UIGestureRecognizerState` as like began ,cancel ,change , ended etc

Comment: did you try this - (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state;
 method of "SWTableviewCell"

Comment: Thank You @wolverine this worked perfect for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add Gesture Recognizer in you cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedRight:)];
[swRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedLeft:)];
[swLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swLeft];
```

and then its selector method

```
-(void)cellSwipedRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // your code
    }
}

-(void)cellSwipedLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said to @kb920 - This approach only recognize the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` State.

Comment: No... it recognise multiple state as I comment in your question `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` ,`UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` , `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` etc

Comment: It worked thank You and also found another solution for this [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) Library

`- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will works for you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwiped:)];
    [swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];


return cell;
    }


    - (void)cellSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
    {
        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view;
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            //..
        }
    }
```