# How to impliment UISwipeGestureRecognizer on UITableView cell?

Tags: iphone, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How can i add swipe gesture in my table view cell? i am using custom cell in tableview and i have to delete that row from table so please guide me how can i use this swipe gesture in table view?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604296/uigesturerecognizer-and-uitableviewcell-issue

Comment: Thanx nikunj you helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely the same as in any other view. Insert this code either in your custom cell's init or in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of your UITableViewDataSource delegate.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myTableViewController action:@selector(removeCell:)];
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

Comment: I am a newbe so please don't mind of my silly questions. please give me some more detail. cz it is not detecting swipe

Comment: try changing the 21 to a 1. That means you are needing 21 fingers on it doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement two delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return YES;
}
```

and other method where you have to perform you editing or deleting code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)  {
        //write delete code.
        [arry removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [Table reloadData];
    }
}
```