# Table View Cell highlight when user swipe

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I try to make row action for `UITableViewCell` and **I have a problem** with highlight while swipe. The user doesn't really select the cell, he simply swipe to left.

My `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       // Sets the inner rectangle to the selected color
        [cell setCellColorWithString:COLORS_ARRAY[4]];
        
        return YES;
    }
```

And my `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` cancel the highlight if this is the right thing to do, but it called too late :/

Can I get any event when the user start/stop swipe to left/right?

Any help will be great.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a swipe gesture recogniser to the table view, find the cell that matches the touch point of the swipe and then unhighlight it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604667/1297633)