# swift GestureRecognizer in cells

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to make long press tableview Cells, But i'm getting error:

> UIGestureRecognizer.Type' does not have a member named 'state'

Here's the code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
        gesture.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        }

func longpressed() {

    if(UIGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){

        print("ended")
    } else if (UIGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){

        print("began")


    }
}
```

And Yes I've created Bridging-Header.h and imported this file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

I want swift tutorial not objective-c!

Comment: Have you tried in adding the gesture to each cell object? No need of importing this class.

Comment: @Amit89 thanks for your reply, This code was in Tableview , And how can i add the gesture in each cell ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIGestureRecognizer and UITableViewCell issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604296/uigesturerecognizer-and-uitableviewcell-issue)

Comment: @iosDev82 Thanks! but this Objective-c and I don't know how to read objective-c codes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a gesture recogniser to your `UITableView` like

```
    var gestureRec = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRec)
```

Implement a `didTap` function, which would look something like this.

```
func didTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if sender.state == .Began {
        var location = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your longPress method:

```
func longpressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

var state = sender.state

if(state.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
    print("ended")

} else if (state.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
    print("began")

}
}
```