# UITableView Using a row as a segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

So I've been trying to get any row to act like a segue to the next class, kind of like how if you swipe left you can delete the row, after adding the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

but instead in stead of deleting it I would like it to show the another class. If anyone could help it would be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `swiprgesturerecognizer` something like,

```
 class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe")
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

func didSwipe(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        let swipeLocation = recognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
        if let swipedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(swipeLocation) {
            if let swipedCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(swipedIndexPath) {
                // Swipe happened. Do stuff!
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

This was an example, manage it as your need. you can add swipegesture's `direction` property for handle particular direction's swipe like `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left` or `Right`.

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290126/swift-add-gesture-recognizer-to-object-in-table-cell) as a reference.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Just one more thing. Rookie question but how do you perform the segue in the code. So in your answer when you say "// Swipe happened. Do stuff!" how do I then get it to show the other class?

Comment: You can performsegue something like `performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)`   here `mySegueID` is segue identifier set from the interface builder from attribute inspector with segue selected

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you would like so that the user would swipe left on a cell, and it would trigger a segue?

If this is the case, you could try adding a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the cell using the `addGestureRecognizer` method, within the `cellForRow` method of the UITableViewDataSource class.

Hope this helps!