# UITapGestureRecognizer breaks UITableView SelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

if I add tapgesture on background view then I have to long press for select cell and if I set numberoftaprequired is 2 the it will be work normally but I have to give one functionality on single tap

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?  Do you want to single tap on a `UITableViewCell` and have it perform an action?  And if so, what do you want the background tap (or double-tap, or long press) to act like?

Comment: Please add enough detail - code in particular - for someone to be able to duplicate your issue. It's **extremely** hard to understand what issue you are facing when your question is but a single sentence.

Comment: Just check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37693082/6080920

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITapGestureRecognizer breaks UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add cancelsTouchesInView to your tap gesture

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourfunction))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

try this