# Swipe multiple UIViews in swift

Tags: swipe

I need to use view swipe gesture down, up, left and then right. But on swift `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` has predeterminate right direction. And I don't know how make this for use other directions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions you can check this page. It worked on me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve different swipe direction using code and Storyboard as well.

1. Using Code

   ```
   var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
   swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
   //Use following Directions as you need
   //UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
   //UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
   //UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
   ```
2. Using Storyboard:

   Select the gesture and in Attribute Inspector select the direction. see the screen shot.
   [image]

**Note: You will need 4 different gesture recognisers for 4 directions**