# Swift Call A Function When Swipe Gesture Ends

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a swipe gesture recogniser in my app, but how can I call a function every time the swipe ends (i.e. call when the user finish swiping and lift up his/her finger)? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recognize swipe in all 4 directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions)

Answer (score 4):

Check the gesture state like this:

```
if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended { //code }
```

Comment: I added `if swipeRightGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended { println("end") }` to the `update` function in my `SKScene`, but nothing was printed in console. Any suggestion?