# Detecting swipes on all four directions on WatchKit using the Storyboard

Tags: swift, watchkit, swipe, apple-watch

I am trying to detect the swipes on the AppleWatch on all four directions. Yet I am not clear how to assign many values to the direction of the WKSwipeGestureRecognizer I inserted in the Storyboard. I tried with:

```
swiper.direction = [.right , .left ,  .up , .down]
```

that was funnily accepted by the compiler, differently of using the bitwise |, but, using this configuration, function:

```
@IBAction func swipe(_ sender: Any) {
    switch swiper.direction {
    case WKSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
        print("Swiped right")
    case WKSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
        print("Swiped down")
    case WKSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
        print("Swiped left")
    case WKSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
        print("Swiped up")
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

is very seldom called and when it is the swiper.direction is invariably .right.

Apple is very cryptic at:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkswipegesturerecognizer/1650828-direction
by saying:

> "The default value of this property is right. You may specify more
>   than one direction to track swipes in multiple directions with the
>   same gesture recognizer."

without revealing how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recognize swipe in all 4 directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions)

Comment: This is not well-explained by the documentation, but the value of the recognizer's `direction` in the handler is _not_ the actual direction of the detected swipe. It's simply the value that you originally set.

Comment: You should check the OptionSet docs. They very clearly explain how to define multiple options.

Comment: The usage of the option set is correct here, @jjatie.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, but the OP appears uncertain as to why.

Comment: Differently of the quoted post, I would like to use the gesture recogniser in the storyboard rather then defining it programmatically, as Apple suggests. As for the optionset docs, they indicate to use the array notation as I did. As for the middle poster, if that is not the actual direction, what it is? And more importantly, how do I get the actual swipe direction?

Answer (score 0):

At any rate, totally ignoring what Apple says, putting four WKSwipeGestureRecognizer in the storyboard each with a different direction and target does the job.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select WKSwipeGestureRecognizer from Utilities box on the right side

2) From the attributes inspectors, check "Delays touches began" and select "Swipe" type that you need

[image]
 -

3) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + drag IBAction to your viewController and implement function