# Ignore/intercept swipes on subview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I currently have a single page swift application (for iOS) running on a custom view controller. Within that view controller, I've embedded another custom UIView to display some content / handle some user interaction.

I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept a UISwipe, which is registered in the custom view controller, and have swift ignore it if it occurs on the embedded view. I know that for taps, I could set my view controller as the delegate for the tap gesture recognizer and do something like the following:

```
// not exact syntax
func gestureRecognizer(touch){
     if (touch.view == self.embeddedView || (touch.view.isDescendantOf(embeddedView))!){
           return false
      }
   return true
}
```

However I can't find any functionality that does the same for swipes. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Its not clear what you want here: should the swipe be ignored only if it *starts* on the embedded view, or should any motion while on that view be ignored? The former is trivial, the later might be more difficult.

Comment: sorry for not being so clear. I would like to ignore the swipe if it starts on the embedded view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Custom View Controller as the delegate of the swipe gesture and override shouldReceiveTouch method.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
     return !CGRectContainsPoint(embeddedView.bounds, touch.locationInView(embeddedView))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I +1'd but don't have enough rep to show it yet. very much appreciated.

Comment: @finn you can (and should if it anwered your question) accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: @finn please accept the answer if its correct, refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: accepted! First post here, still getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

swift 5

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return !containerView.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: containerView))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a UISwipeGestureRecognizer wich u can implement like this:

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeRightDetected))
self.embeddedView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

Look at this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215844/5664183

Comment: I understand how to implement a swipe gesture recognizer. I'm trying to figure out how to ignore the swipe if it starts on my embedded view. Sorry if that wasn't clear.