# Swift Navigation Controller swipe to go back anywhere

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller with an embedded Navigation Controller and I want the presented controller to be able to swipe anywhere to return back to the root controller. How is this possible is it by using SwipeGesture or Extending the navigation controller?

Also please note that the presented controller is a table view and has cell nibs.

Comment: a normal swipe gesture should go back to the root view controller, or a swipe from the left edge?

Comment: That's the point I don't want to swipe from the left edge any more. I want to swipe from anywhere in the view.

Comment: do you still want the interactive transition? do you want to disable the swipe from the edge, am I correct?

Comment: I want to be able to swipe left from anywhere in the view to dismiss the controller.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza How to make it interactive with table view? Do I use the leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt table view method, or is there another way? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your indications a normal gesture recognizer on your tableview is enough.

I would do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(fromGesture:)))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

@objc func dismiss(fromGesture gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    //Your dismiss code
    //Here you should implement your checks for the swipe gesture
}
```

And if you want to disable the default behavior of the back gesture:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

I hope it helped. :)

Comment: you are welcome. :) would you mark it as accepted answer for the next who will have the same problem please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all viewControllers from navigationController except the one currently displayed and the one I want to go back to with swipe.

**My viewControllers hierarchy:**
AViewController -> BViewController -> CViewController

Let's say I am currently displaying CViewController and want to swipe back to go to AViewController. By default, when swiping back from CViewController I would go back to BViewController, which is preceding CViewController. So when CViewController is on display I delete BViewController from navigationController and I can nicely swipe back to AViewController

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll {
  !($0 is AViewController) && !($0 is CViewController)
}
```