# Configure UISwipeGestureRecognizer to fail?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to configure a UISwipeGestureRecognizer with e.g. direction: .left to fail if the swipe is going diagonal with the y component larger than the x component? (my gesture recognizer seems to not give up as long as there is a tiny component going in its direction)

[image]

(would like to have the swipe going more down not recognized)

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem with image or more description?

Comment: your question is a bit foggy.. however you might try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions