# How do I create a UISwipeGestureRecognizer programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

```
private let swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = {
    let swiper = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(movedUp))
    swiper.direction = .up
    return swiper
}()

private let swipeDown: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = {
    let swiper = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(movedDown))
    swiper.direction = .down
    return swiper
}()
```

creating my swipeUp and swipeDown gesture recognizers

```
func movedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("UP")
}
func movedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("DOWN")
}
```

my functions to be called when the swipe is recieved

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

}
```

adding my gesture recognizers in viewDidLoad

my program runs, but nothing happens when i swipe, what am i doing wrong?
Thankyou everyone

Comment: Change moveup and movedown param type to UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: @JitendraTanwar Why? The current parameter type is correct.

Comment: You are trying to add swipe gestures to a view controller's view. What other views are in the view controller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private lazy var swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = {
    let swiper = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(movedUp))
    swiper.direction = .up
    return swiper
}()

private lazy var swipeDown: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = {
    let swiper = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(movedDown))
    swiper.direction = .down
    return swiper
}()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

func movedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("UP")
}

func movedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("DOWN")
}
```

Comment: Please don't post just code. Explain what was wrong and how your answer fixes the problem. "Try this" is not a useful description.

Comment: Can't you see the difference in the code? Its the same code as yours just "let" replaced with "lazy var". And description is required when the code works according to your requirement. First try and run it then ask the questions.

Comment: I'm offering you advice on how to write a better answer. People shouldn't have to run a diff on the two versions of code. Good answers explain the issue and explain the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried func movedUp(sender: UIGestureRecognizer)