# UISwipeGestureRecognizer addGestureRecognizer to view in childview error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

after some years I tried again to work with XCode to write some little apps for iOS.

My MainViewController contains these lines in viewdidload:

```
UIStoryboard* overviewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *overviewController = [overviewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Overview"];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:overviewController];

...

[self addChildViewController:nav];
[self.view addSubview:nav.view];
[nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

the Controller behind the Overview contains the whole gesture recognition in view did load:

the property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureUpDown;
```

viewdidload:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

// gesture recognizer top
self.swipeGestureUpDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreen)];
self.swipeGestureUpDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.swipeGestureUpDown.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeGestureUpDown];
```

and swipedScreen only an nslog:

```
- (void)swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"somewhere");
}
```

THE overviewcontroller contains a tableView with custom cells.
The maincontroller passes this overviewcontroller as rootcontroller to a navigation, which should be slideUp if you swipeUp, and slideIn if you swipeDown. The maincontroller is calling the navigationcontroller with rootcontroller as you've seen above.

Nothing happens, no gesture is recognized, and in some tries it crashes with this message

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

does somebody now what to do?

Comment: You need to provide the complete error. The complete error states the class and method names.

Comment: I probably know what's happening. I don't want to jump the gun though. Could you post your swipedScreen function's definition? Ok, why don't you just post the whole swipedScreen function whatever it is.

Comment: now i added the 5 lines of code :)

Comment: did i forgot an : at the end of @selector(swipedScreen)? I think yes, but really doesnt change something.

Comment: Yes you are right, that's what I thought. :) But didn't that resolve the error?

Comment: no, now it doesnt crash, but the debug is not printing anything.. maybe because its UP and DOwn on an tableView.. but how to fix that?

Comment: Oh yes! You did the same mistake that I had done. self.swipeGestureUpDown.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);
This does not work. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319209/setting-direction-for-uiswipegesturerecognizer You need to add two separate swipes. With current code NSLog should work for right swipe I think.

Comment: doesnt work either if i only add one recognizer (only up). i really think it has to do something with uitableview which is scrollable in UP an DOWN and so its not that easy to recognize own swipes?

Comment: yeah right swipe and left are working -.-

Comment: It seems you are right ahmet2106. Looked around a little, swipes are delivered to uitableview at the highest priority. In fact I feel that's how it should be because having two different actions for same gesture in a single view would be a weird UI design.

Comment: @ahmet2106 Could you please try setting scrollEnabled property to NO? "When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain." This design will work only if your content in table fits in single screen. Please let me know.

Comment: Funny, with scroll enabled false it works ;) but thats not what i need. and I also not want to write my own scroller if swipe recognized. so ill try maybe something else

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question came up in the comments. Just consolidating it here.
There were a few issues.
**First:**

```
self.swipeGestureUpDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreen)];
```

`@selector(swipedScreen)` is missing **:** at end of `swipedScreen` which makes it unrecognizable as the definition of the function is `- (void)swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture`

**Second:**

```
self.swipeGestureUpDown.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);
```

Having single gesture recognizer for two directions of swipe does not work. For details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319209/setting-direction-for-uiswipegesturerecognizer). You will need to have a dedicated gesture recognizer for each direction.

**Third:**

Most important of all was trying to add Up and Down direction swipes on `UITableView` which won't work as long as scrolling is enabled in `UITableView` as it has its own default actions to handle these swipes which prevents it from being handled manually.
 But if you have very limited content in the table and don't need scrolling, you can set `scrollEnabled` to `false` which will make  `UITableView` stop using the gestures and forward the gestures higher up the responder chain. Refer `scrollEnabled` description [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). (`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`.)